# View Certain Running Scripts via PS

Tags: php, linux, grep, ps

I need to get a list of all running PHP scripts but piping my grep through "ls" just gives me a list of all PHP files in my current directory, not the names of the currently running scripts.

How do I accomplish this?

**I was able to get the count of currently running PHP scripts**

```
root@myhost:/var/www/cron/jobs# ps -ef | grep *.php | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

**This is kinda what I need:**

```
root@myhost:/var/www/cron/jobs# ps -ef | grep *.php | grep -v grep | ls
```

THANKS!

Comment: To use the output of a command in the next command after a pipe, use `xargs`.

Comment: `ps` offers no way to list "processes running php scripts". Even when you are referring to php cli then only those processes with get mentioned that got a "php script" in their command line call. This is _very_ unreliable. What for example about php scripts not being called *.php? What about scripts being opened with an editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the count with this:

```
root@myhost:/var/www/cron/jobs# ps -ef | grep *.php | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

then

```
root@myhost:/var/www/cron/jobs# ps -ef | grep *.php | grep -v grep
```

should just list the scripts running because all that `wc -l` does is count the output lines, the lines that contain the scripts you're running.